# Char Password box as in TextBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

How to set the characters in the textbox as in Password Box or how to make binding Password Box ?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PasswordAdmin, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource LTB.TextBox}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the control PasswordBox:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Here some usefull links:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox(v=vs.100).aspx

A link about the risk of binding the Password:
http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/security-risk-in-binding-wpf-passwordbox-password/

Comment: You can't and often shouldn't bind the Password Property. It's not a Dependency Property. Reason behind that is, that it would hold the password in plain text in the memory. Workarounds for Binding (which can be ok sometimes) and Tutorials on how to use the PasswordBox right are more than hundrets around the web.

But the direction to the PasswordBox Control is absolutly right! =)

Comment: You are Right, i edit my response. As in the first link he also can use an attached beaviour.